# Boolean operators in filter of list

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I am trying to filter a list of files by two conditions. And the following code works

```
import java.io.File

val d = new File("/home/loom/shp")
val dirList = d.listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory).toList
dirList.map({
      _.listFiles.filter(f => f.isFile).filter(f => f.getName.endsWith("shp")).toList.map(println)

   // !! Inducde an error
   // _.listFiles.filter((f => f.isFile) && (f => f.getName.endsWith("shp"))).toList.map(println)
})
```

However, if I tried to combine both conditions in one filter condition (as it is shown in the commented line), I have received the following error message:

> Error:(32, 27) missing parameter type
>         _.listFiles.filter((f => f.isFile) && (f => f.getName.endsWith("shp"))).toList.map(println)

It claims that I missed the parameter type. What should I correct to make my code work?

Comment: All those `.toList.map(someFunctionReturningUnit)` should have been `.foreach(someFunctionReturningUnit)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the boolean `&&` operator on two functions, which simply won't work. What you want is a function from `File` to `Boolean`, which you can write like this:

```
_.listFiles.filter(f => f.isFile && f.getName.endsWith("shp")).toList.map(println)
```

`f.isFile` is a boolean and `f.getName.endsWith(...)` is a boolean, so `&&` will do what you expect.